# Problem with session managment

Tags: cookies, php

I have PHP application that contain three small applications. Each application have own users and they are unique for all system. I have problem with session management. When one user is logged in `server.com/app1` and write `server.com/app2` second application log in automaticaly with this user. But this user hasn't any rights on this application. In login page I do this:

```
$status = $user->status;

if($status != 4) {
        $auth_key = session_encrypt($userdata, $passdata);

        $SQL = "UPDATE customer SET auth_key = '$auth_key'
                WHERE username = '$userdata' ";

        $auth_query = mysql_db_query($db, $SQL);

        setcookie("auth_key", $auth_key, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, "/app1", "server.com", false, true);

        // Assign variables to session
        session_regenerate_id(true);
        $session_id = $user->id;
        $session_username = $userdata;

        $_SESSION['cid'] = $session_id;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $session_username;
        $_SESSION['status'] = $status;
        $_SESSION['user_lastactive'] = time();

        header("Location: index.php");
        exit;
}
```

But this doesn't work. Can someone help me how to repair my sessions. Thanks :)

Comment: I do not see the part where you test for correct authentication in your code, is it possible that users are automatically logged in?

Comment: BTW: what is session_encrypt? is it a function defined by you, php only has a sessino_encode function.

Comment: session_encrypt is my function. Where I should test for correct authentication?

Comment: when do you set the `$user->status` var?

Comment: Did you test this with different browsers?

Comment: @Jeremy S I set this var when user is logged successful.

Comment: @Gumbo Yes I test it with all browsers

Comment: @n_yanev: What are “all browsers”?

Comment: I think the code of server.com/app2 should have a flag that is set to check as per the active user and the code within ths page are executerd only if the flag is set else an error to be displayed of insufficient rights

Comment: @Angelin Nader I'll try this.
@Gumbo Chrome, Mozilla, IE, Opera and Safari

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly, your problem is that your three apps are independent but are hosted on the same server/use the same php instance. This results in their using the same php session, and the latter gets filled up with inappropriate garbage.

You've several potential solutions:

The first and easiest is to prefix your sessions in the way or another, i.e. use `$_SESSION['app1']['param']` or `$_SESSION['app1_param']` rather than `$_SESSION['param']`.

Another, if you've php installed as cgi rather than as an Apache module, is to configure each individual apps' php.ini in such a way that they're no longer sharing their session_id (i.e. configure the session cookie name and/or path) nor storing the session data in the same location (which is somewhere in /tmp if I recall correctly).

Answer (score 1):

If you would like your sessions to be handled independently by each app then it might be easier to just set the unique sessionid for each app in the cookie.

```
setcookie("auth_key", $auth_key, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, "/app1", "server.com", false, true);

setcookie("auth_key", $auth_key, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, "/app2", "server.com", false, true);

setcookie("auth_key", $auth_key, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, "/app3", "server.com", false, true);
```